# Why do some variables' names end in underscore?

Tags: tokens, openzeppelin, state-variable

On Open Zeppelin's [ERC20 BasicToken contract](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/zeppelin-solidity/blob/master/contracts/token/ERC20/BasicToken.sol) the variable `totalSupply_` follows a naming convention I haven't seen before.

Is that to differentiate it from the function `totalSupply()` below or is there another reason?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes that is precisely why.

If `totalSupply_` was named `totalSupply` it would clash with the function `totalSupply()` and you would get the following error message:

`DeclarationError: Identifier already declared.`